# Is it bad practice to make a simple if-else statement not on one single line in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, interpreter

At my internship I have noticed that a coworker of mine has manipulated one of my functions from doing this:

```
if isSinglesMatch:
    name1 = GetName(1, "BUG")
    name2 = GetName(2, "BUG")
else:
    name1 = GetName(1, "Short")
    name2 = GetName(2, "Short")
```

to this:

```
name1 = GetName(1, "BUG" if isSinglesMatch else "Short")
name2 = GetName(2, "BUG" if isSinglesMatch else "Short")
```

I see that his code is shorter, but is there any advantage like it being interpreted faster? Is it bad to keep it the way I had it in the first place? In my opinion, it is easier to debug my code (there are a few extra variable assignments that I left out of this example).

No one at my internship has told me that I should change the way I do things, I just noticed that this is the way my coworker likes to do it.

Comment: This would fit better on Code Review, but if it's moved: Please add the GetName method text...

Comment: In this *particular case* there is no difference. In general, there is no reason to prefer a *conditional expression* versus a full `if-else`, although, it will come down to subjective things like readability.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga does this apply only to Python? Or is it okay to leave it like my code in compiled languages as well?

Comment: @user12809744 There is no general answer here. But I would guess that in languages that use an optimizing compiler, this is even less of a difference.

Comment: `In this particular case there is no difference.` There is definitely a difference. The first one only evaluates the condition once, while the second one do so twice. Timed the time it takes to execute both 100000000 time, and the first code took `23.139553546905518` while the second code took `30.313650131225586`. It wouldn't make much difference for most projects, but that is still terrible practice to repeat the same computation just for the sake of saving a few lines.

Comment: @JordanBrière so just to be clear, you would prefer my code over my coworkers code?

Comment: From the two snippets you provided, yes, definitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, it is worse to have the same condition in two lines. Your code is more understandable. Best would be:

```
mode = "BUG" if is_singles_match else "Short"
name1 = get_name(1, mode)
name2 = get_name(2, mode)
```

Note the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ever curious about impact on the interpreter, you can always use [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). I was curious so ran it myself:

I added some preamble just to define `GetName` and `isSinglesMatch`, but this is what the disassembly looks like for your example:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (False)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (isSinglesMatch)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object GetName at 0x7f4e90337810, file "test_a.py", line 2>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('GetName')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (GetName)

  5          12 LOAD_NAME                0 (isSinglesMatch)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       38

  6          16 LOAD_NAME                1 (GetName)
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             20 LOAD_CONST               4 ('BUG')
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             24 STORE_NAME               2 (name1)

  7          26 LOAD_NAME                1 (GetName)
             28 LOAD_CONST               5 (2)
             30 LOAD_CONST               4 ('BUG')
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             34 STORE_NAME               3 (name2)
             36 JUMP_FORWARD            20 (to 58)

  9     >>   38 LOAD_NAME                1 (GetName)
             40 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             42 LOAD_CONST               6 ('Short')
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             46 STORE_NAME               2 (name1)

 10          48 LOAD_NAME                1 (GetName)
             50 LOAD_CONST               5 (2)
             52 LOAD_CONST               6 ('Short')
             54 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             56 STORE_NAME               3 (name2)
        >>   58 LOAD_CONST               7 (None)
             60 RETURN_VALUE
```

And for the more terse version:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (False)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (isSinglesMatch)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object GetName at 0x7f13f8f1f810, file "test_a.py", line 2>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('GetName')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (GetName)

  5          12 LOAD_NAME                1 (GetName)
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             16 LOAD_NAME                0 (isSinglesMatch)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       24
             20 LOAD_CONST               4 ('BUG')
             22 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 26)
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Short')
        >>   26 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             28 STORE_NAME               2 (name1)

  6          30 LOAD_NAME                1 (GetName)
             32 LOAD_CONST               6 (2)
             34 LOAD_NAME                0 (isSinglesMatch)
             36 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       42
             38 LOAD_CONST               4 ('BUG')
             40 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 44)
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Short')
        >>   44 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             46 STORE_NAME               3 (name2)
             48 LOAD_CONST               7 (None)
             50 RETURN_VALUE
```

Ignoring everything up until `MAKE_FUNCTION/STORE_NAME`, you can see there's an ever so slightly different performance cost. However, I would personally sacrifice the performance in this context for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Programming is highly opinionated, there are probably reasons why he does it this way. 
One is for readability. A lot of times, developers sacrifice a negligible decrease in performance in favor of being easy to read. If you have an easy to read code, maintaining it wouldn't be as painful as hard to read ones.

I think in this case you have to ask your coworker. They probably follow some code style that you might not be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad practice. It just depends where you use it.

I've noticed the same standards at several companies. Typically, conditionals will be shortened down to one line -- through the ternary operator -- so the code looks cleaner.

This is great if the conditional is simple. In the example you provided, the revised code is cleaner, and the two variables `name1` and `name2` are declared only once.

While the original code is functional and works, think of the revised version as a **shortened way of doing the same thing**.

If you'd like to determine when you should break down a condition, think of whether or not it could be written much more simply (while still understandable). If it results in multiple nested ternary operators, it may be best to avoid it in that scenario.